# AJAX window doesn't work with cyrillic letters - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encoding, modal-dialog

I've tried [Tinybox2](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/) (pure javascript) and [Colorbox](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) (works with jquery) (modal windows with source from another url).

Both work fine with latin letters, but not with cyrillic letters. 
I do not know how to solve this problem with encoding...

Tinybox2 doesn't work at all with cyrillic. 
Colorbox shows next text in opened modal window:

`Request unsuccessful: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`

Run on local machine.

How to solve this?

Comment: Which encoding have you set in your html header?
Try to encode with [ISO-8859-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5)

Comment: I found solution! Server side technology: Django+Mako. So in template I defined at first line `## -*- coding: utf-8 -*- ` and it works now!!! Thank for your responses!!!!

Answer (score 2):

try running this header with php at the very top of your document.

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
?>
```

Comment: I'm using it with Django (Python)

Comment: Adding that to the top of the page should fix your problem then.